# Various scripts I see will not run through python

Tags: python

I am very confused as to why I get syntax errors when attempting to run scripts such as the one contained in the answer below:

[How do I download PDFs from PubMed, given their IDs?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/100927/how-do-i-download-pdfs-from-pubmed-given-their-ids/291166#291166)

Am I not supposed to run scripts like this in Python? Where can I run it if not?

Comment: maybe a better link: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/100927/117549 -- also, you're aware that the first line of the file is: `#!/usr/bin/env bash` ?

Comment: Doesn't that mean I just have to run this script in Linux? Or is the env file unique for everyone's system? Sorry, I'm very inexperienced with all of this.

Comment: It's a bash script, not a python script.

Comment: You should show us how you're running the script; then we can show you what's wrong or where exactly the misunderstanding is.

Comment: @jordanm that was my issue thanks. I just didn't understand why python wouldn't run the script, which was a general misunderstanding that was hard to put into words.

Answer (score 1):

Because they are not Python scripts. That's a bash script, as you can see in the first line (`#!/usr/bin/env bash`).

To run that script just save it to a file, give it executable permissions and open it or just run `bash /path/to/script` in the Terminal.